# Getting 6 columns instead of 5 after transposing rows

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

[image: screen shot of results]

Edit: I can see how my post can be confusing, it was hard for me to describe what I'm trying to do.

I want the end result of the transpose to look like it does in the screen shot. The issue is why I'm getting 6 columns when I only want 5. The values in Col D:H are supposed to be the beginning and end. But instead they are shifted to the right and Col C has values I do not want there. As well as the issue of why the second row appears to be shifted down.

More detail: The first value in each group of 5 cells is a serial number. The next for cells are measurements. I need these groups of 5 to stay in their original order. But right now the groups are going from high serial number to low serial number and I need it to be the reverse of that.

Original Post: I am trying to get each 5 rows to transpose into their own single row in 5 columns but in reverse and staying in the descending order. The first row in every 5 rows in Column A is a serial number, as you can see the numbers descend. I need to keep the 5 rows together but reverse the serial numbers.

I am close but the values in column D are sequential serial numbers that are supposed to be in column C. And the values in column C seem to be the last value in a set of 5 rows. Can someone please help me.

```
My code:
Dim bottomB As Integer
bottomB = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim TR As Long
For TR = bottomB To 2 Step -5
Range(Cells(TR, "A"), Cells(TR + 5, "A")).Copy
Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Next TR
```

Comment: Which 5 rows are you trying to transpose? Do you mean every fifth row?

Comment: You say 5 rows but your table has 6 columns, and what happened to the first few values from ColA - is the destination table complete?

Comment: It is supposed to be 5 columns and I'm getting 6, thats the problem. That and the next rows after the first are shifted down for some reason.

Comment: TobyPython its every sequential group of 5 rows. The first row in a group is the serial number and the next 4 values are a measurement. The Serial numbers go from high to low and i need to them to be transposed as low to high but keeping the measurement values in the original order.

Comment: It would be better to show the result you want, rather than the wrong one...

Comment: _I'm getting 6 columns instead of 5_. Probably because `Range(Cells(TR, "A"), Cells(TR + 5, "A"))` is 6 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now revised your code to do what I think you intend it to do. The main difference is between the definition of the range to copy. Of course, if you start from row 1 and add 5 you end up at row 6 which is the start of the next group, not the end of the current one. Therefore the correct formula is to define the range as rows 1 to 1+4. And if you start with the last row and add 4 cells below it you will have only a single value in that range because all cells below the last one are blank. Therefore you must start at the cell which is 4 cells above the last one.

```
' 139
Dim bottomB As Integer
Dim TR As Long

bottomB = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 4
For TR = bottomB To 2 Step -5
    Range(Cells(TR, "A"), Cells(TR + 4, "A")).Copy
    Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Next TR
```

I think my adjustments cure the faults you have been complaining about. However, I point out that the code is excessively reliant upon the last row in the column being a fourth measurement of a set. Any deviation at that point must cause failure for the entire operation.

Please consider adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the loop and setting the property to True again thereafter. That will greatly speed up the operation and avoid any flicker on the screen as data change quickly.

With all that was said done your code would look like this:-

```
Sub TransposeRows_2()
    ' 139
    Dim bottomB As Long
    Dim TR As Long
    
    bottomB = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For TR = (bottomB - 4) To 2 Step -5
        Range(Cells(TR, "A"), Cells(TR + 4, "A")).Copy
        Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next TR
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your approach but I should have been more clear with my request. I want the end transpose to look like how I have it in my screen shot. Except for the fact that Col D:H need to be shifted over to be C:F. The current values in Col C are not supposed to be there. And the first row only has 1 value when it should be 5 values. It's as if the sequential rows after the first one were shifted down and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I now understand what you want to do and have therefore changed my answer completely. Please add `Application.CutCopyMode = False` at the bottom of my revised code to remove trace of the copying operation.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim bottomB As Integer, b,c,d,i,j
Dim a as Collection
Dim TR As Long

Set a = New collection

bottomB = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' Put the data in a collection
For TR = bottomB To 2 Step -5
b=Range(Cells(TR, 1).Value
a.Add b.value
Next TR

Calculate 1/5th of total items in collection
c=Round((a.count)/5)
d=0

' You'll have to specify the start positions you want to paste
For i= Row1 to Row1+c
For j= Column1 to Column5

' Paste collection into cells
Worksheets("").Cells(i,j).Value=a(d)
d=d+1
Next i
Next j
```

Comment: I couldn't get your code to run, it doesn't seem to like the line:
b=Range(Cells(TR, 1).Value

Comment: If you haven't specified the sheet in the code somewhere else it would need to be Worksheets("Worksheetname").Cells(TR,1).value